# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to code a little social media using express and mongoose principally, and I got the error "ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT" while running this code. How am I supposed to fix this ?

```
const UserModel = require("../models/user.model");
const ObjectID = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;


module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

  try {
    await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      {
        $set: {
          bio: req.body.bio,
        },
      },
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.status(200).json(docs);
        if (err) return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: The error must come from some other part of your code that is executed when you make the problematic request. Can you share that request and also the relevant code?

Comment: I'm executing this code on Postman, by selecting "PUT" and entering {"bio": "..."}. The problem can possibly come from this part of code (the routes): `const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller')
const router = require("express").Router();
const authController = require("../controllers/auth.controller");
// auth
router.post("/register", authController.signUp);
router.get('/', userController.getAllUsers);
router.get('/:id', userController.userInfo)
router.put('/:id', userController.updateUser)
module.exports = router;`

Comment: and when I'm a checking on the database, I can see the bio I have just modified

Comment: You must check if some earlier code already executes `res.send` or something similar and then calls `next()`.

Comment: One function used for showing a profile is doing this. Do I need to change something?

Comment: After sending a response with `res.send` or similar, you must not send another or call `next()`. To just log something, use `console.log`.

Comment: Actually I found out it was a problem with the await and the findAndReplace. But anyway thanks a lot for your help 